# Proper wildcard multi field query with the official mongo-go-driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

I have a database field:

```
            "sessionid": "C-dhf",
            "given": "NURSE ",
            "family": "SHARK",
            "name": "SHARK, NURSE",
```

I am attempting to create a query that will query the db looking for records that family starts with "s" given name starts with "n". I am using the following to create the filter.

```
        {"sessionid", "C-dhf"},
        {"$and", bson.A{
            bson.D{{"family", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^s", Options: "i"}}},
            bson.D{{"given", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^n", Options: "i"}}},
        }},
    }
```

The filter value used in the find is:

```
[{sessionid C-dhf} {$and [[{family {"pattern": "^s", "options": "i"}}] [{given {"pattern": "^n", "options": "i"}}]]}]
```

The find is:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), filter, findOptions)
```

It returns all records in the db as though it is not even looking at the filter.

What is the proper go syntax for a multiple field wildcard query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all listed conditions are in logical AND connection (`$and`), so you don't need to add that:

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"sessionid", "C-dhf"},
    {"family", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^s", Options: "i"}},
    {"given", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^n", Options: "i"}},
}
```

The syntax and structure you used would be appropriate if you'd wanted logical OR connection: if you'd wanted documents with given session ID, and whose family name starts with `s` or given name starts with `n`. That could look like this:

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"sessionid", "C-dhf"},
    {"$or", bson.A{
        bson.D{{"family", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^s", Options: "i"}}},
        bson.D{{"given", primitive.Regex{Pattern: "^n", Options: "i"}}},
    }},
}
```

Comment: you example says OR yet your description is an and, specifically what I want. I need all three to be included in the returned set. Please clarify

Comment: @DonaldFrench My first example does not say OR, that's what I think you want based on the question. Please you clarify the question which one you want, but I presented both (AND and OR) in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I want the AND. I misunderstood your last statement. It is good to know both formats.